# pip: Show version of dependencies required

Tags: pip, huggingface-datasets

`pip show package_name` only shows the package dependencies. It does not show the specific version of dependencies required to install that package. For example, `pip show datasets` has the following lines in its output:

```
Name: datasets
Version: 2.7.1
...
Requires: pyarrow, tqdm, huggingface-hub, numpy, fsspec, aiohttp, packaging, responses, requests, xxhash, dill, multiprocess, pyyaml, pandas
...
```

I want to know the specific version of say `huggingface-hub` that is required by `datasets==2.7.1`. How can I find that?

I tried `pip show --help` but it doesn't seem to have any options for this.

Comment: `pip` has no way to know that, only the packager has. That `Requires: …, huggingface-hub, …` line was put into the package by the creator and `pip` just shows it. If the packager hasn't provided versions — that's all you can get.

Comment: I see. But that information is accessible by pip, right? Because when installing the package, pip installs the specific versions of the dependencies too.

Comment: That information becomes available at installation time — `pip` connects to PyPI.org and tries to install the latest version available for its Python version. For example the current latest release of `huggingface-hub` is [0.11.1](https://pypi.org/project/huggingface-hub/0.11.1/) and it requires Python >= 3.7. If you use Python 3.6 `pip` will try to find a compatible version and most probably finds https://pypi.org/project/huggingface-hub/0.4.0/

Comment: In this case, I think the creators have provided the dependency versions but pip is not showing it. I don't think the version of dependency to install is being decided by the python version, but rather the package version. For example: When installing [`transformers==4.9.1`](https://pypi.org/project/transformers/4.9.1/) (requires `Python>=3.6.0`) in a `Python==3.8.10` env, by your reasoning, the version of `huggingface-hub` that installs would be the most recent one that can run on `Python==3.8.10`. That would install `huggingface-hub==0.11.1`. However it installs `huggingface-hub==0.0.12`.

Comment: There is [code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/d51e7c7e8265d69db506828dce77eb4ef9b72157/setup.py#L188) in transformers' source and it's probably buggy. I downloaded [transformers-4.9.1-py3-none-any.whl](https://pypi.org/project/transformers/4.9.1/#files) and in its `transformers-4.9.1-py3-none-any.whl/METADATA` there is fixed `Requires-Dist: huggingface-hub (==0.0.12)` so this what is installed. What does `pip show transformers` show for you?

Comment: `Name: transformers`
`Version: 4.9.1`
`Requires: packaging, huggingface-hub, tqdm, requests, numpy, pyyaml, tokenizers, filelock, sacremoses, regex`
`
It does not show the version of huggingface-hub.
Do you mean that even though the version `huggingface-hub==0.0.12` is hardcoded, in principle `transformers==4.9.1` would work with later versions of `huggingface-hub` (as long as they work with my env Python version)

Comment: "*Do you mean that even though the version `huggingface-hub==0.0.12` is hardcoded, in principle `transformers==4.9.1` would work with later versions of `huggingface-hub`…*: Nobody knows without thorough testing. It's impossible to deduce automatically.

Comment: "*It does not show the version of huggingface-hub.*" Well, so `pip` doesn't show even that small amount of information available to it. :-(

Comment: This is indeed a real problem. Even though `grep Requires-Dist /path/to/site-packages/ansible_core-2.14.2.dist-info/METADATA` might contain version constraints, that information is silently discarded in the `pip show` output. Incredibly annoying. :|